# How can I rename a video gotten from android mediastore?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

How can I rename a video gotten from mediastore without deleting or corrupting it?

I tried using this code gotten from a similar question but it deletes or corrupts the video whose name I changed.

```
String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim(); 
video.setTitle(title);
File parentFile = videoFile.getParentFile();
if (parentFile != null) {
String path = parentFile.getAbsolutePath(); 
String extension = videoFile.getAbsolutePath(); extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf(".")); 
String newPath = path + "/" + title + extension; 
File newFile = new File(newPath); 
boolean rename = videoFile.renameTo(newFile); if (rename) {
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver(); resolver.delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{videoFile.getAbsolutePath()}); 
Toast.makeText(context, "renamed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT). show(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why is the "/" there in your new file? You're not renaming your file, you essentially want to move it somewhere if you mess with the path. To rename the file, just change the name of the file, not the entire path

Comment: Sir, are you suggesting that I remove the slash from the new path name?

Comment: Yeah, or otherwise please post a sample of the original filename and new filename. Like what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: So it should be "path + title + extension;"?. As stated Sir, I just want to rename the video.

Comment: It's not working, actually the original approach seems intuitive. E.g, the original file path might be /Storage/downloads/videos/The Amazing Spiderman, the absolute file path would be /Storage/downloads/videos. The new path the original code was the absolute file path + the new name + the extension.

Comment: But they're not working, both yours and the one I posted. Is there an entirely different method of renaming a video in Android?

Comment: Why is nobody responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it

```
textViewRename.setOnClickListener(v1 -> { String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim(); video.setTitle(title);
String extension = videoFile.getAbsolutePath(); extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf("."));
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2); values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, title);
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title + extension );
context.getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Video.Media. EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values,
MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{videoFile. getAbsolutePath()});
if (videoOptionListener != null) { videoOptionListener.onEdit();
} dialogRenameVideo.dismiss(); });
```